# Variance stabilisation

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, variance, random-variable

$Y$ has mean $\mu$ and variance function $V(\mu)$.

If $V(\mu) = \alpha.\mu^v$ then $h(y) = y^{(2-v)/2}$ is variance stabilising which means that $Var(h(Y))$ is approximately constant.

I tried to prove it computing $Var(h(Y)) = E(h(Y)^2)-E(h(Y))^2$  but I'm completely stuck. Can you help ?

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach would be via [Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables).

You rewrite $h(Y)$ as $h(\mu+(Y-\mu))$ and expand about $h(\mu)$. You can then take expectation and variance.

When finding expectation the expansion is usually taken to the third term (the second being 0); variance is often only taken to the first non-zero term, and in each case the rest goes into the 'remainder'.